# XUnit, NUnit, MSUnit all run all tests twice VS2022

Tags: nunit, xunit, visual-studio-2022

In Visual Studio 2022 the test runner for XUnit, NUnit and MSUnit all run the tests twice (I switch the project between the three).

For XUnit (the last one I landed on and plan on staying with) I have the following nuget packages installed: xunit (2.4.1) and xunit.runner.visualstudio (2.4.3)

I have no relevant VS extensions installed (that I can tell... nothing with XUnit, NUnit, or MSUnit in the name).

My project file is nice and simple:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>

    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AForge.Video" Version="2.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="AForge.Video.FFMPEG" Version="2.2.5.1-rc" />
    <PackageReference Include="DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers" Version="3.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" Version="96.0.4664.4500" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.3">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="avcodec-53.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="avdevice-53.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="avfilter-2.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="avformat-53.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="avutil-51.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="postproc-52.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="swresample-0.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="swscale-2.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

I'm at a loss. Any help appreciated!!

I'm at a loss.

Comment: I recreated my test project using the "XUnit project" standard template. Copied over my tests... and bam same problem. Tests run twice.

Comment: Having exact same issue. Only solution I have found is to upgrade to more stable, older version of Visual Studio. Absurd that they manage to release such a buggy software and noone notices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had the same problem.  I also noticed that having Fine Code Coverage enabled causes every test to be run in the background even if you only choose a single test in the Test Explorer.

What seems to work is to enable RunMsCodeCoverage in the Fine Code Coverage settings.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me!  My set up is VS 2022 v17.6.2, .Net core 3.1.0, SpecFlow 3.9.22, Specflow.NUnit 3.9.22 and NUnit3TestAdapter 3.17.0

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem.

Disabling Fine Code Coverage extension fixed the issue for me.

If that does not solve it, maybe try disabling all the extensions and running the tests. Then enable them one by one.

Comment: Seems to work for me on v17.4.3. This seems to start happening some where around December. Didn't not suspect this one at until you mentioned it. Thanks.